# iOS: How to save text from UITextBox to file

Tags: ios

I want to save a text string from a file when a user presses a button. Could this file be a .plist? Then, later, I want another function to read the text from the file and turn it into a variable. How is this possible?

Snarky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to save some user default setting for future reference, check out `NSUserDefaults`. Easier than dealing with files if you're really just trying to save some setting.

If you really want to read a string from a file, go to your Xcode organizer, go to documentation, click on the search icon, and type in "Reading Strings From" and one of the top links will be how to read and write to files.

Answer (score 3):

Saving:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/myFile.plist"];
    //Create the file if it doesnt exists
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
           NSDictionary *emptyDic = [NSDictionary dictionary];
           [emptyDic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        }
    //Save the text using setObject for key or something similar, you could even use a NSArray instead
    NSDictionary *dic  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    [dic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Loading:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myFile.plist", documentsDirectory];
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

I think you can't use a .txt file directly but I have never tried it.

Comment: You can read text file with NSString's `initWithContentsOfFile`. You can save it with `writeToFile`.